# Cannot login using devise in production w/ Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, devise

I have devise up and running perfectly on my localhost. As soon as I push it to the server and set to production (apache / passanger), I cannot login. I can login however using production webrick on the server.

If I give the wrong password, I get a bad password error. When I use the correct password I redirected to the login redirect page, but I'm not logged in.

I am using active record sessions, not sure if that has anything to do with the problem.

The login is successful as I can see in the logs where the current user stats are updated after login, but then when the new page loads user_signed_in? returns false.

Here is the query I see in the logs for reference :

```
SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "last_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = 1  [["current_sign_in_at", "2015-01-03 19:34:11.930934"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2015-01-03 19:29:33.496977"], ["sign_in_count", 18], ["updated_at", "2015-01-03 19:34:11.931889"]]
```

**Update:** I came across this possible solution which has worked for others:
Set `config.http_authenticatable = false` in your config/initializers/devise.rb. to prevent HTTP Auth from Apache interfering. This did not fix the problem for me.

**Update 2**: I read somewhere that this may be caused by an apache configuration issue, and someone else was able to fix it by switching to nginx. Made sense to me since webrick is working fine even in production mode. I made the switch and still have the same problem.

Any help would be most appreciated. I'll continue researching as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what fixed it for me:

I was running ruby-2.0.0-p195 and I upgraded to ruby-2.2.0

Don't know exactly why this worked but it did. Hopefully this helps someone else. Also if you're having a similar issue take a look at the troubleshooting steps I did in the updates. Perhaps that will help you out as well.